# Gatling Error: Could not find or load main class Engine

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I installed the latest IntelliJ idea, latest `maven 3.6.3`, `Java 1.8`, set the JAVA_HOME / JRE_HOME env variables. Then generated a Gatling project using `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=gatling`. In summary, I followed the instruction [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-gatling-tests-implementation-environment/). I have installed the Scala plugin for IntelliJ idea as well. When I try to run the Gatling engine by right-clicking on the Engine class, 
I am getting below error. can someone tell me what's going on here? I tried all the suggestions online, but no luck so far. Thanks

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe".....

Error: Could not find or load main class Engine

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.gatling</groupId>
  <artifactId>pert-tests</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <gatling.version>3.2.1</gatling.version>
    <gatling-maven-plugin.version>3.0.3</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-recorder</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 10):

[David Montaño](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571966/david-monta%c3%b1o)... after manually marking src/test/scala as Test Sources Root, I got "Error:(11, 18) illegal cyclic inheritance" as mentioned by [Rasika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157280/rasika)

I just found that scala 2.13.1 is not compatible with gatling. I removed scala 2.13.1 from global libraries list and added scala 2.12.10. Tests working fine now. Here are the steps

1. Right click project folder in IntelliJ and choose 'Open Module Settings'
2. Under 'Platform Settings' select 'Global Libraries'
3. Here, remove scala-sdk-2.13.1 and add scala-sdk-2.12.10
4. Rebuild the module

Comment: Been struggling with this issue on and off for ages with Gatling... this solution downgrading to 2.12 finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me when I manually marked the `src/test/scala` as *Test Sources Root* and rebuild the project.

[Mark as Test Sources Root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RBcf.png)

It should be picked up automatically by IntelliJ but it wasn't the case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Still the same issue @David Montaño, The solution compiles fine, however when I have a look at the solution folders, I am unable to find any bin folder with complied binaries, Could that be the reason?

Comment: I tried adding scala SDK 2.13.1 to Global Libraries in project settings, now i m getting a compilation error as Error:(11, 18) illegal cyclic inheritance involving trait Iterable
  Gatling.fromMap(props.build)

Answer (score 0):

Tied both :
marked the src/test/scala as Test Sources Root and rebuild the project.

Mark as Test Sources Root
And
Under 'Platform Settings' select 'Global Libraries'

Here, remove scala-sdk-2.13.1 and add scala-sdk-2.12.10

then works.